# Import Excel to Datagridview

Tags: excel, vb.net, import

I'm trying to import a data set from Excel to a DB with VB.net. With this code I always get the error

> External table is not in the expected format.

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 

Private Sub Button_Import_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Import.Click
    Try
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim Ds As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\matil\Desktop\Data.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [ExportedFromDatGrid$]", MyConnection)
        Ds = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyAdapter.Fill(Ds)
        Me.DataGridView_Kontakte.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

My DB looks like this
[image]

and my Excel File like this
[image]

Comment: This message is to do with the file extension of your Excel file. Sometimes opening the file in Excel and going to `File > Save As` then changing the extension fixes the issue (Try saving as a 2003 Excel file etc.)

Comment: The Jet provider can not read a .xlsx file format.  Use the ACE provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change**

```
  MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\matil\Desktop\Data.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
```

**to**
use this

```
 MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path));
```

set the path to get the connection

Comment: Awesome Thank you, any chance that i can set path to open a load file window and search my system for the file?

Comment: In the open file dialog you can set the directory and file name as well

Comment: tryed with this here:           Dim Path As New OpenFileDialog()
            MyConnection = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", Path)     but i only get errors

Comment: Error:" The value of String canot be converted in OleDbConnection", without the dialog works fine

Comment: updated the solution. chekc the answer. I feel you might be taking it straigh forward answer. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

From Excel to Datagridview?  It can be done like this.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\vb.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Please see the link below for all relevant information, and several relater links as well.

http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_import.htm